# Scala Spring IoC and JSF

Tags: java, spring, scala, jsf

I've got a spring injection prolbem which I've been trying to solve for 4 days an not getting anywhere:

In my spring config I have:

```
<bean id="applicationCache" class="domain.ui.ApplicationCacheServiceImpl">
    <property name="divisionSelectOptionsCache" ref="divisionSelectOptionsCache"/>
</bean>

<bean id="divisionSelectOptionsCache" class="domain.jsf.DivisionSelectOptionsCache"></bean>
```

**ApplicationCacheServiceImpl.scala looks like this:**

```
class ApplicationCacheServiceImpl extends ApplicationCacheService{
   var divisionSelectOptionsCache: DivisionSelectOptionsCache = _

   def setDivisionSelectOptionsCache(dsoc: DivisionSelectOptionsCache) ={
     divisionSelectOptionsCache = dsoc
   }
 ....
```

**DivisionSelectOptionsCache.scala looks like this:**

```
class DivisionSelectOptionsCache extends Converter{
   val options = mutable.Map[String, DivisionSelectOption]()
   var em: EntityManager = _

   // Just left this in case its  relevant. Throws no errors though
   @PersistenceContext
   def setEntityManager(entManager: EntityManager) = {
      em = entManager
   }
   ....
```

The application compiles and a war is built. However when I deploy it I get the following exception msg:

```
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jan 18, 2013 7:56:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationCache' defined in class path resource 
applicationPersistence.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: 
Failed to convert property value of type '$Proxy15 implementing javax.faces.convert.Converter,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,
org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised' to required type 'com.domain.jsf.DivisionSelectOptionsCache' 
for property 'divisionSelectOptionsCache'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Cannot convert value of type [$Proxy15 implementing javax.faces.convert.Converter,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised]
 to required type [com.domain.jsf.DivisionSelectOptionsCache] for property 'divisionSelectOptionsCache': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
 .....
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type '$Proxy15 implementing javax.faces.convert.Converter,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised' to required type 'com.domain.jsf.DivisionSelectOptionsCache' for property 'divisionSelectOptionsCache'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [$Proxy15 implementing javax.faces.convert.Converter,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [com.domain.jsf.DivisionSelectOptionsCache] for property 'divisionSelectOptionsCache': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
  at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:485)
  at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:516)
....
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [$Proxy15 implementing javax.faces.convert.Converter,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [com.domain.jsf.DivisionSelectOptionsCache] for property 'divisionSelectOptionsCache': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
  at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:247)
  at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:470)
  ... 31 more

Jan 18, 2013 7:56:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStop
FINE: Stopping filters
```

**So:**
`ApplicationCacheServiceImpl` is looking for spring to inject into property `divisionSelectOptionsCache` a type corresponding to `DivisionSelectOptionsCache` this is correct and as defined in the spring config xml file.

Class `DivisionSelectOptionsCache` `extends` `Converter` so there should be not problems there.

So I'm stuck. I've even tryed taking out spring IoC and using google Guice  to give compile time checking rather than deploy time checking (no xml config files), but that didn't work because of the applications dependency on Spring for providing managed jsf beans.

Please help as I'm on the verge of telling the client that it can't be done.

Thanks

Comment: Just a small tip: you don't have to write Java-style getters and setters by yourself. You can just write e.g. `@BeanProperty var divisionSelectOptionsCache: DivisionSelectOptionsCache = _`

Comment: Googling your error message gives results that look quite relevant, e.g. http://www.bitsandpix.com/entry/spring-error-cannot-convert-value-of-type-proxy-to-required-type/

Comment: try spring-scala api http://blog.springsource.org/2012/12/10/introducing-spring-scala/

Answer (score 0):

Use a decompiler like the one at http://java.decompiler.free.fr/ to check the bytecode which the Scala compiler is generating.  It may well be that it isn't doing what you think.

Answer (score 0):

Too much time passed from the time you asked the question, but I'm gonna answer it maybe this is someone else problem,

This problem occurs when Spring is using `JDK proxy`. As in `JDK proxy` all the classes should have 'Interface' and your `DivisionSelectOptionsCache` class doesn't implement any interfaces then there is such a problem,
Two solution for that:

- Implement interface for all classes
- Use `CGLIB` proxy

In order to use `CGLib` proxy, you should add the lib in the lib folder and use

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

in `application-context`. The default value of `proxy-target-class` is `false`, which is `JDK proxy`.